# add timestamp to images within array

Tags: php, mysql, function

i have a php code that works great everything is fine. all images are uploadet to server and also store info in database. BUT i have decided to add time to each uploaded file right before file extension and also want to store that information in database.

This is my code:

```
<?php
function jaunProd() {
    include 'database.php';
    $message = '';
    if (isset($_POST['jaunProdPoga'])) {
        if(!empty($_POST['prod_vards']) && !empty($_POST['kat_id']) && !empty($_POST['subkat_id']) && !empty($_POST['prod_apraksts'])  ){
            $prod_vards = $_POST['prod_vards'];
            $kat_id = $_POST['kat_id'];
            $subkat_id = $_POST['subkat_id'];
            $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
            $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
            $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
            $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
            $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
            for ($i=0; $i <count($tmp_name_array); $i++){ 
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i],'img/prod_img/'.time().$name_array[$i]);
            }
            $prod_kods = $_POST['prod_kods'];
            $prod_cena = $_POST['prod_cena'];
            $prod_apraksts = $_POST['prod_apraksts'];
            $stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO produkti (prod_vards, kat_id, subkat_id, prod_img1, prod_img2, prod_img3, prod_img4, prod_img5, prod_kods, prod_cena, prod_apraksts) VALUES ('$prod_vards', '$kat_id', '$subkat_id', '$name_array[0]', '$name_array[1]', '$name_array[2]', '$name_array[3]', '$name_array[4]', '$prod_kods', '$prod_cena', '$prod_apraksts')");
            if($stmt->execute()){
                $message = '<p class="green">Produkts pievienots </p>';
            } else {
                $message = '<p class="red">SEIT LAIKA MIR KLIASHF </p>';
            }
        } else {
            $message = '<p class="red">Lauki ar * nedrīkst būt tukši! </p>';
        }
    }
    echo $message;
}
?>
```

Here `move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i],'img/prod_img/'.time().$name_array[$i]);`
i add time to file but this adds to front of file, but how to add after name and before extension.

And also i dont know how to store that dynamical info in database.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$ImageName = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($_FILES['myfile']['name']));
$ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
$ImageExt = str_replace('.', '', $ImageExt);
$ImageName = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
$NewImageName =  $ImageName .time(). '.' . $ImageExt;
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i],'img/prod_img/'.$NewImageName);
?>
```

Comment: when i put in strtolower my file_array i have error: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: change  $_FILES['file_array']  instead of $_FILES['myfile']

Comment: still the same.

Comment: did you get file array in  $_FILES['file_array']?